# Make icon in button have different effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery button like this: http://codepen.io/rlkelly/pen/GZgVQr where I have a box with an icon.  I want the box to change if you click it, but I want the icon inside to open a modal.  Right now the icon doesn't override the jQuery of the box, is there a way to do this?

The html is:

```
<button class="box" id="box" type="submit" name="response" value="Accept" style="width: 49%;">
    <div id="yes-notes" class="icon-wrapper pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil custom-icon"><span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span></i></div>
    <p class="text" id="caption">
        Yes
    </p>
</button>
```

And the jQuery is:

```
$("#box").click(function() {
      $("#box").attr('class', "box2");
      $("#box2").attr('class', "gray");
      $("#caption").attr('class', 'text2');
      $("#caption2").attr('class', 'text');
});
```

I just want to craft a function that overrides the jQuery from the #box if you click the `<i>`.

Comment: So you mean when a `<i>` is clicked you should run a different function and the `#box` event should not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with jQuery.

Basically, what you need to do is block the event propagation once the icon is clicked. This is done by returning false in the event handler, which means the button's event handler won't also be triggered.

```js
$(".box").on("click", ".custom-icon", function() {
  $("#trace").append("<p>Icon clicked</p>");
  return false;
});

$(".box").on("click", function() {
  $("#trace").append("<p>Button clicked</p>");
});
```

```css
.custom-icon {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="box" id="box" type="submit" name="response" value="Accept" style="width: 49%;">
  <div id="yes-notes" class="icon-wrapper pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil custom-icon"><span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span></i>
  </div>
  <p class="text" id="caption">
    Yes
  </p>
</button>
<div id="trace"></div>
```